# PHP with HTML output formating

Tags: php

Im trying to display this field and its displaying out of order ex:

> GloriaBainsA special thanks to for fostering !

It should be :

> A special thanks to Gloria for fostering Bains !

```
<?php 
   if( get_field('special_thanks_option')) { 
       echo "A special thanks to ". 
       the_field('special_thanks').
       "for fostering ". 
       the_title().
       "!";
   } else{}
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as i'm still learning php .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ben Pearl Kahan is correct it is impossible to be 100% without knowing what those two functions do.

That being said though, it looks like they almost certainly print the value and not return it.

Try this instead maybe...

```
<?php 
   if( get_field('special_thanks_option')) { 
       echo "A special thanks to "; 
       the_field('special_thanks');
       echo " for fostering "; 
       the_title();
       echo "!";
   } else{}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the functions `the_field()` and `the_title()` do (whether they return the values or print them), it's hard to see - but try loading the values separately and then printing them together:

```
<?php 
    if( get_field('special_thanks_option')) {
        $x = the_field('special_thanks');
        $y = the_title();

        echo "A special thanks to $x for fostering $y!";            
    } else{}
?>
```

Comment: I didn't try this but I don't see why it wouldn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Just make your close php and add html to it.

Change it to:

```
  <?php 
   if( get_field('special_thanks_option')) { 
       echo"<p>A special thanks to </p>".
       the_field('special_thanks').
       "<p>for fostering </p>" . 
       the_title().
       "!";
   } else{}
?>
```